# difference between SmartGit "revert" and "revert & commit"

Tags: smartgit

I have edits and a commit I want to undo.

SmartGit offers "revert" and it also offers "revert & commit". What is the difference?

Do either of these modify source code or are they strictly changes within Git itself.

Comment: I can't find anything on "revert & commit."  Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen when you use the "revert" control it will show a dialog that asks you to choose between "revert" and "revert & commit".

Comment: I decided to do a `git reset --hard 123abc` since it is easier to understand the consequences. Still an answer to this question would be valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Both **Revert** and **Revert & Commit** will modify your source code in the *working tree*. **Revert & Commit** will -- in addition -- also immediately commit these modifications. With **Revert** you have to manually **Commit** yourself. The advantage of **Revert** is that you can tweak your commit, if necessary. Also, **Revert & Commit** may be unable to actually perform the commit due to conflicts.

Comment: If I want to undo edits and undo a commit it sounds like "revert" is sufficient. What is the scenario in which a person would want to use "revert & commit"? It seems that to revert would be to move back the "recording head". If that is what revert does then I can't imagine the need to also commit.

Comment: If you want to undo a commit, this means you want to have another commit with the reverse changes. So in either case, you will finally have to commit. I'd recommend to set up a small test repository (including a clone of that repository) and experiment with both options.

Comment: I don't think that to undo a commit needs to involve committing the reverse changes. Does `git reset --hard 123abc` perform a commit? My understanding is that it does not.

Comment: No, `git reset --hard` resets your current branch to the specified commit. However, this won't help to undo a single, old commit.